# Laravel dynamic controller route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, url-routing, url-mapping

I use Laravel 5.4 and now I want to make dynamic route to controller which mean I can access `UserController` and `Profile` function throw route directly, for example.

```
GET http://localhost/user/profile?userid=123
```

The example URL above will access `UserController` and function `profile` with dynamic parameters after `?`. And if I want to access different controller, I just need to change `user` param to `Controller` name.

I created a route like this and it works.

```
Route::get('v1/{controller_name}/{function_name}/{query?}', function ($controller_name, $function_name){

    $app = app();
    $controller = $app->make('\App\Http\Controllers\Api\\'.$controller_name.'Controller');
    return $controller->callAction($function_name, $parameters = array());
});
```

But I don't know how to pass parameters.

Any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly, but you might want to check out the following.

```
Route::get('v1/{controller_name}/{function_name}/{query?}',
        function ($controller_name, $function_name, $query = null) {
    var_dump($controller_name, $function_name, $query);
});
```

visiting http://localhost/v1/my-controller/my-function/my-parameter URL outputs:

```
string 'my-controller' (length=13)
string 'my-function' (length=11)
string 'my-parameter' (length=12)
```

visiting http://localhost/v1/my-controller/my-function URL outputs:

```
string 'my-controller' (length=13)
string 'my-function' (length=11)
null
```

And to extend the idea further, it is possible to write:

```
Route::get('v1/{controller_name}/{function_name}/{query?}/{query2?}',
        function ($controller_name, $function_name, $query = null, $query2 = null) {
    var_dump($controller_name, $function_name, $query, $query2);
});
```

http://localhost/v1/my-controller/my-function/my-parameter/my-parameter2

```
string 'my-controller' (length=13)
string 'my-function' (length=11)
string 'my-parameter' (length=12)
string 'my-parameter2' (length=13)
```

http://localhost/v1/my-controller/my-function

```
string 'my-controller' (length=13)
string 'my-function' (length=11)
null
null
```

Then you can use:

```
// ...
return $controller->callAction($function_name, $parameters = [
    'param1' => $query,
    'param2' => $query2,
]);
// ...
```

Comment: I've found my own solution but thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @JohnnyNguyen Just curious, what was your own solution?